# How to tell if cdfv2 file is encrypted using python?

Tags: python, file, libmagic

I have an file which has been encrypted by Zed!.
This is identified by

```
file --mime-type test.zed
```

as "application/CDFV2-encrypted"

However, when using python and the module filemagic:

```
with magic.Magic(flags=magic.MAGIC_MIME_TYPE) as m:
mime = m.id_buffer(file)
```

the exact same file is identified as:
"application/cdfv2"

They both use libmagic, so I was sure that I would get the same type in both cases. However, according to [this](http://mx.gw.com/pipermail/file/2015/001717.html); the file command searches for

> a user stream in the CDF file called "EncryptedPackage"

which apparently gives the suffix "-encrypted".

Now for my questions:

- How does one define "user stream"?
- Can I perform the check by examining the binary file in python?
- Is there any other python module
  which can provide information regarding if the file is encrypted or not?

I am using filemagic 1.6 and libmagic 5.22